# How to write š, č on Latvian keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

In Ubuntu, to write ā, ē, ī, ū (vowel with macron or *garumzīme*) I type

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> + <kbd>letter</kbd>

with the Latvian keyboard set

To write ģ, ķ, ļ, ņ (consonant with cedilla or *mīkstinājuma zīme*) I type

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>  + <kbd>letter</kbd>

But how to type č, š, ž (consonant with caron, *háček* or another type of *mīkstinājuma zīme*)

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>???</kbd> + <kbd>letter</kbd>

The keyboard settings are the following:
[image]
The **compose key** is <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>

[image]

Other options for the compose key are

<kbd>Disabled</kbd>, <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Right Win</kbd>, <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Menu</kbd>, <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>.

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> does not appear as an option.

Comment: <AltGr> and <Right Alt> is [the same thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key). And it's that key you are using for all the examples you show, isn't it?

Comment: It is but your answer did not work for me.

Comment: If you would change the compose key to "Disabled" it would work. But then some of the other examples you showed would need to be typed in a different way. Possibly it would be a good idea in your case to pick some other key as the compose key, e.g. "Right Ctrl". Having "Right Alt" (or "AltGr") ready for its original purpose is useful for many things.

Comment: Yes, in case of setting the compose key to Disabled your answer works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Latvian keyboard layout is prepared for the characters you mention:

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> = š

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> = Š

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> = č

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> = Č

[image]

Comment: Your answer does not work for the keyboard settings (see posted image).

Comment: @Viesturs: It does for me. You are supposed to e.g. hold down <AltGr> while pressing the <S> key. Please see the image I added to the answer. <AltGr> is there labelled "Level3".

Comment: Well, no. We might have different keyboards, different settings.

Comment: @Viesturs: When seeing your own answer, I realize that you must have defined <AltGr> as the compose key. Hence it will not work for its original purpose, which is the probable explanation why you can't use the built-in method in the Latvian keyboard layout.

Answer (score -1):

Type

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> + <kbd>letter</kbd>

Do not forget to use

<kbd>Shift</kbd>

to access

<kbd><</kbd>

Comment: What you show there is a way to accomplish what you want which has nothing to do with the Latvian keyboard layout. For that to work, you must have designated the <Alt> key as the [compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#compose). Please add that to your answer to make it useful for other users.